# How to find out if it's the first boot on the current day

Tags: windows-7, boot, batch, cmd.exe

I have a `batch` file in my auto start which should behave a bit different on the first boot.

How can I find out if it's the first boot on the current day via Windows `cmd`?
May be there's some way reading the Windows event log of the current day and count the boot events?

Comment: Why not use a `lock` file?. In the batch file see if there exists a file named with todays date. If no create the file (it is first boot). if yes it is not first boot. You could even tidy up and delete older files from prevous days.

Comment: I also thought about that but may be there's another way without creating files

Comment: My gut feeling says this is easier than parsing event logs (which is certainly possible). For example if you look at the event logs you have to take care of edge cases (like the system starting on a wake up timer to download updates for example).

Comment: [It](http://uptimeexe.codeplex.com/) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work under the assumption that is called when the machine boots.

`wevtutil` is used to search the `System` event log for the last two *Startup events* (`EventID=12`) and from them the date is extracted. If both dates are the same, then this is not the first startup today.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "boot1="
    set "boot2="

    for /f "tokens=2 delims=T: " %%a in ('
        wevtutil qe system /count:2 /rd:true /q:"Event[System[(EventID=12)]]" /format:text 
        ^| find "Date:"
    ') do if not defined boot1 ( set "boot1=%%a" ) else ( set "boot2=%%a" )

    if "%boot1%"=="%boot2%" (
        echo This is NOT the first boot on the current day
    ) else (
        echo This IS the first boot on the current day
    )
```

Comment: Sorry for not reacting to you answer back then. I really like your solution. I think for Windows 10 some modifications are needed since Win10 uses the hybrid boot and just wakes from hibernate (event id 107) but generally that's what I needed.